# $\det:U\to\mathbb{R}$ has surjective derivative for every $x$ $\iff$ no matrix in $U$ has dimension $\le n-2$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra

Let $U\subset \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ be a open set of matrices $n\times n$. Show that the function $\det:U\to\mathbb{R}$ is a submersion (its derivative is surjective for every $x$) $\iff$ no matrix in $U$ has dimension $\le n-2$

My book solves this as following:

The $n^2$ coordinates of the jacobian matrix are the numbers $(-1)^{i+j}X_{ij}$ where $X_{ij}$ is the determinant of the $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ matrix you get when omiting the $i$-th columns and $j$-th line (or the reverse, don' t remember). So $x$ is a critical point of $\det\iff X_{ij}$ is $0$ for every submatrix of our matrix which implies that if all the submatrices determinants $X_{ij}$ are $0$ our matrix has dimension $n-2$. WHY?? Also, what is the connection of the derivative being surjective with all of this???

Comment: If it had dimension $n$ it would be invertible ; if it had dimension $n-1$ then at least one of the $X_{i,j}$ wouldnt be null

Comment: Could you be more specific? I couldn't understand exactly

Comment: The point is that it must have dimension $n$ or $n-1$

Comment: Tried to be more specific in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming by dimension you mean rank.

- $\forall (i,j), X_{i,j} = 0 \iff \det x=0$
  This comes from the [Laplace expansion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion). 
  And $\det x = 0 \iff x$ is not invertible $\iff$ the rank of $x$ is not $n$.
- $\forall (i,j), X_{i,j} = 0 \iff$ the rank of $x$ isn't $n-1$. 
  This comes from the fact that the rank of a matrix is the size of the largest non-vanishing minor.

Thus, $x$ is a critical point $\iff x$ has rank $\leq n-2$.

Now, what's the link with $\det$ being a submersion ? Well, $D_{\det} \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^{n^2}, \mathbb{R}^{n^2})$, and thus it is a surjection iff it is an injection, iff its kernel is $\{0\}$.

Does that make it more clear?